# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure Issue when getting sequence value

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to insert multiple records in a table using loop and getting sequence number for that using below method. It is getting sequence number for very first time alone and during next iteration below exception is coming.Please help in resolving this

```
14:03:51.928 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to session
14:03:51.938 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR u.s.m.e.p.o.b.c.ORBudgetController - 2020/08/26_14:03:51.938|1|pa23690|bearer 6d7417d8-6835-485e-956d-c362cb7bce2b|createRecord|possible non-threadsafe access to session
```

```java
@Override
public int getNextSequenceNumber(String seqName) {      
    int nextValue = 0;       
    String strQuery = "SELECT " + seqName + ".NEXTVAL FROM DUAL";
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(strQuery);
    BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) q.getSingleResult();
    nextValue = bd.intValue();
    return nextValue;
}
```

Comment: You should not do it manually, you should use the [GenerationType.SEQUENCE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the sequence automatically, do it manually is a bad practice and can bring you problems in the future. There are several JPA strategies to automatically generate the sequence, this, for example, is [The Sequence Strategy](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated)

```
@Entity
// Define a sequence - might also be in another class:
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class EntityWithSequenceId {
    // Use the sequence that is defined above:
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Id long id;
}
```

You can also use The Auto Strategy

```
@Entity
public class EntityWithAutoId1 {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) long id;
     
}
```

Comment: Thank you,will follow like above